# Fetching data from Firebase and storing in local state is undefined

Tags: firebase, next.js

I am fetching data from firebase with the result being undefined.  When I comment out the elements that use the data, the data gets stored in state, I uncomment the elements and they render without any issues. When I make changes and save the file, it reverts back to being undefined and the elements do not render.

Here is the code I am currently working with :

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { make, model, id } = router.query;
  const [singleCar, setSingleCar] = useState([]);

  const docRef = doc(db, "car listings", `${id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      await getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
        const carData = doc.data();
        setSingleCar(carData);
      });

      await onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
        const carData = doc.data();
        setSingleCar(carData);
      });
    };
    fetchDetails();
  }, [singleCar]);
```

I know I am both fetching a single doc and adding in a real-time listener but I wasn't sure which would be the best action, given the getDoc method only runs once after fetching the document so thought it might be better to have a real-time listener also in place.

Here is what I am rendering, my thinking is that if state is undefined, render the Loader component until the state has changed with the appropriate data.

```
{singleCar === [] ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Container maxW="container.xl">
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-around">
            <Image
              w="500px"
              src={singleCar.carImages[0].fileURL}
              borderRadius="10px"
            />

            {/* <CarImageGalleryModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} /> */}
            <Box
              display="flex"
              flexDirection="column"
              justifyContent="space-between"
            >
              <SingleCarPrimary
                make={singleCar.carDetails.make}
                model={singleCar.carDetails.model}
                year={singleCar.carDetails.year}
                doors={singleCar.carDetails.doors}
                engineSize={singleCar.carDetails.engine_size}
                fuelType={singleCar.carDetails.fuel_type}
                body={singleCar.carDetails.year}
                price={singleCar.carPrice}
              />
              <ContactSection />
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <CarSummary carDetails={singleCar.carDetails} />
          <SingleCarDescription carDescription={singleCar.carDescription} />
        </Container>
      )}
```

Here is how the information is being stored in Firebase to give you an idea of what data is being retrieved.

[image]

Backend: Firebase version 9
Frontend: Next.js / Chakra UI

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be with the queried document identifier that is not referring to any document, hence the `undefined` properties result you are getting.

Here down a list of fixes you should apply to your implementation to mitigate such an issue.

You are better using a separate `loading` state that is will be reset once data is loaded so that it can reflect both loading and empty results:

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { make, model, id } = router.query;
  const [singleCar, setSingleCar] = useState({}); // the car should be an object and not an array
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const docRef = doc(db, "cars", `${id}`); // avoid spaces in document names

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      await getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
        setLoading(false);
        if (doc.exists()) {
          setSingleCar(doc.data());
        }
      });
    };
    // fetch the `car` data
    fetchDetails();
    // then attach the change listener
    await onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      const carData = doc.data();
      setSingleCar(carData);
    });
  }, []); // you should not rerun the effect on state changes as this will keep on reattaching state listener again and again and may fall into endless fetching loops
```

You component declaration then may be updated as follows (you may still need to update it to reflect empty car state => the data is fetched but there is not car reflecting the queried `id`):

```
{loading === true ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : (
    <Container maxW="container.xl">
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-around">
        <Image
          w="500px"
          src={singleCar.carImages[0].fileURL}
          borderRadius="10px"
        />

        {/* <CarImageGalleryModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} /> */}
        <Box
          display="flex"
          flexDirection="column"
          justifyContent="space-between"
        >
          <SingleCarPrimary
            make={singleCar.carDetails.make}
            model={singleCar.carDetails.model}
            year={singleCar.carDetails.year}
            doors={singleCar.carDetails.doors}
            engineSize={singleCar.carDetails.engine_size}
            fuelType={singleCar.carDetails.fuel_type}
            body={singleCar.carDetails.year}
            price={singleCar.carPrice}
          />
          <ContactSection />
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <CarSummary carDetails={singleCar.carDetails} />
      <SingleCarDescription carDescription={singleCar.carDescription} />
    </Container>
  )}
```

Comment: I seem to still be getting undefined so as you say, there could be an issue with the id.  What's weird though, for example, recently when I added in a console log, all the data was fetched no problem and rendered onto the page.  Do you think it would be best to put the docRef in useEffect?

Comment: Ok so I added the docRef to useEffect (both outside and inside fetchDetails function) with no difference.  It's logging the correct id but the doc method just doesn't seem to recognise it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the method of getServerSideProps which I think removes the need for useEffect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).